# Grab variable wihin a line of text that contains constants and other variables

Tags: batch-file

I would like to use as the variable for my code below, instead of what came after ClassName=in 1.txt, I would like what came in-between this:

EntryText=Ship sunk!|Grid AO 77| **Grab variable HERE**, *(notice the comma at the end)*

So grab after the text line ending with the second | and before the comma.

The text line before the variable will be the same and constant **EXCEPT** after "Grid" there could be a word or a different two pair of letters and numbers, or any mixture of letters and numbers up until the |

So I am trying to use as a variable, what is in between:

EntryText=Ship sunk!|Grid *(Any combination of letters or numbers)*| **(variable)**, *(comma)*

So grab in between the second | and the comma. Than you.

```
@echo off

copy 2.txt 2.txt-backup

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

>2.txt (
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" 2.txt-backup') do (
    ( echo !ln!| findstr "^Type=206$" >NUL && set ln=ln ) || (
        set "ln=%%B"
        if "!ln:~0,6!"=="Class=" (
            findstr /c:"ClassName=!ln:~6!" "E:\Dropbox\New folder\Log_*.txt" >"E:\Dropbox\New folder\null" && (
                echo Class=ShipDummy
                set "ln=Type=206"
            )
        )
        if #!ln!==# (echo;) else echo !ln!
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=|" %%C in ("%%B") do for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%D in ("%%C") do echo %%D
```

Comment: How do I apply that? Thank you.